# How to access SPL token data in our Solana smart contract

Tags: solana-program, rust, smart-contract

I have created SPL token. I want to access this token data in my rust smart contract so that I can get information about which user has how many tokens? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Anchor, you can do the following to pull data from a given token account

**In #[derive(Accounts):**

```
#[account(mut)]
pub token_mint: Account<'info, token::Mint>,

#[account(
   mut,
   token::mint = token_mint,
   token::authority = payer,
)]
pub payer_token_account: Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>,

#[account(mut)]
pub payer: Signer<'info>,
```

**In your instruction logic:**

```
let token_amount = ctx.accounts.payer_token_account.amount; // pulls token account balance
let check_mint = ctx.accounts.payer_token_account.mint; // pulls associated mint, should match "token_mint"
```